# tcpdump traffic to a remote host?

Tags: monitoring, http

I unfortunately have to work with a publicly accessible 3rd party badwebsite.example.com where only the login form is served via HTTPS. The inbox, messenger, tickets queue - all go through HTTP. Is there some magic

```
tcpdump -As0 host badwebsite.example.com and tcp port http
```

voodoo that would allow someone who is **neither** in mine nor the host's network to sniff that traffic? I'm not talking about hacks, MITM, DNS injections, etc., just general sniffing of any unsecured website. I can't imagine how it would be possible since the traffic doesn't go through the aggressor's machine but I've been told it's unacceptable "for obvious reasons".

Comment: Either you don't care about people that could spy on it or you do.  It can't be ok for the ISP and their backbone and their interconnections to other parts of the global network and the other ISP, etc.  If it is not encrypted, someone out there could **potentially** look at it.

Comment: @JuliePelletier I agree. I just want to make sure I'm not stupid. All the parties you mention are between me and the website's host so it makes sense for them to be able to peek on my unencrypted packets. This certain someone, however, would have to gain access to any of those nodes first, right?

Comment: Yes but you can not have any clue how that part of the network is managed or who has access to it.  So if you worry about the exchanged data, then you must encrypt it.  This is like hiding a sophisticated digital key under your balcony.  You can't be sure that no one will find it.

Comment: Under your constraints you are perfectly secure. Of course the constraints might not be very realistic. (Using remote sniffing functions in OS or router is possible but it would fall under 'hacking' so does propagating false routes by adversaries or nation state agencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To sniff traffic you must either have access to a system on the path or you must be able to redirect the routing of the IP packets in a way you get on the path.

Both is common for unauthorized access. Most routers and servers allow to trigger dumping or redirection of traffic.

You asked for doing that without cracking so there is no threat in your very specific scenario.

BTW: I personally think threats often come from the local network. It is not unlikely that persons in a local network with access to sniffing has the biggest incentive to invade privacy (because they actually know the targets personally). This can be true for household, school or work settings. Sniffing in that setting would be immoral (and most likely illegal) as well, but it does not always require specific system hacking.

Comment: Legality depends on your local laws and whatever contract you've signed but it surely would be immoral.